# Bypass 500 folder limit in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

In our company we use `Outlook 2016`. Our `service department` has got the problem that it comes to the 500 folder limit. We sort our emails by customer/project. So is there a way how to bypass/get around this problem? Some plugins or tweaks I could install?

Comment: Although there are workaround/configuration to extend the limit, it's not recommended to do so, as it may cause performance issue in Outlook. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2768656/outlook-performance-issues-when-there-are-too-many-items-or-folders-in

Comment: We are currently implementing a new `ERP System` were we won't need outlook for this case anymore. So it's just a temporary solution 

Answer (score 1):

If using Office 365, then according to its Roadmap Outlook has improved
synchronization of folders by removing the 500 folder limit for shared mailboxes.

Otherwise, here are some reported workarounds:

- The thread
  [Method to deal with "too many folders" in Outlook](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28999218/Method-to-deal-with-too-many-folders-in-Outlook.html)
  has this user report:

  > Simply unchecking 'Cached Mode' and 'Download Shared Folders' then relaunching Outlook did not work. I needed to remove the Profile from the PC entirely [Control Panel-> Mail-> Profiles] and then recreate another Profile. When launching Outlook needed to add the account without selecting 'Cached Mode'.
  >
  > This has resolved the issue without needing to edit the server registry or allow other Users to have more than 500 folders.
- The Microsoft article
  [Exchange Store Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/ff477612(v=exchg.141))
  offers the register update of creating in the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem`,
  a new value named `MaxObjsPerMapiSession`, and in it create a
  DWORD (32-bit) named `objtFolderView` that is set to a value higher than 500.
- Another option is to grant access to individual folders within the mailbox
  instead of to the entire mailbox.
  You can grant access to folders with the PowerShell cmdlet of
  [Add-MailboxFolderPermission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps).

(Future Outlook updates may disable some of the above workarounds.)